# Вопрос по шаблонизатору jinja

Tags: django, jinja2

Проблема такая при добавлении картинки в HTML я использовал код:

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="{% static 'img/{{ post.image }}' %}" alt="">
  <div class="item_text">
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но путь до картинки не правильный. Скажите чем можно заменить `{% static 'img/{{ post.image }}' %}`

Comment: Во-первых, это не jinja. Во-вторых, что такое post.image?

Comment: Это jinja post.image это название файла, которое берётся из БД.

Comment: Во-первых, это не jinja. Во-вторых, а почему вы в базе храните просто название файла и не используете какой-нибудь ImageField?

Comment: А что это если не jinga? C ImageField сейчас попробую.

Comment: Это просто шаблонизатор, встроенный в Django, он не имеет отдельного названия. И кстати покажите правильный путь до картинки, который вы ожидаете увидеть в html-коде

Comment: static/img/image.png

Comment: На скорую руку можно написать что-то вроде `{% static 'img/' %}{{ post.image }}` Это кривовато, но работать будет. Не кривовато придётся конструировать ссылку [в Python-коде за пределами шаблона](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57150372) (во вьюхе или в модели)

Answer (score 0):

В файле **settings.py** добавить

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

в **urls.py** проекта добавить

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

и

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

в самом шаблоне

```
{% load static %}
```

и путь до картинки будет такой

```
<img src="{% static post.image.url %}" alt="">
```

Но это только для статики, для медия типо картинок для постов и т.д. наверно лучше использовать **MEDIA_URL = '/media/'** смысл примерно такой же